# Display an XML in browser using data from DataTable + ASP.Net handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, browser, httphandler

I need to display XML in Browser, with these criteria:

1. It should be through Handler for ASP.Net
2. Data is coming from database directly which is stored in DataTable.
3. Using this data table, I need to display XML in browser directly.

What I did is:

[image: This code is written in ProcessRequest method where is final method is called. GetFeedData is where my SQL query is and returning table. The output for the table is also proper.]

Or you can find:

```
private void BuildAYSONationalFeed(HttpContext context, string data)
{
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GetFeedData();

        MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
        dataTable.WriteXml(str, true);
        str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str);
        string xmlstr;
        xmlstr = sr.ReadToEnd();

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Charset = "";
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
        context.Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF - 8'?>< bookstore >< book >< title > Everyday Italian </ title >< author > Giada De Laurentiis </ author >< year > 2005 </ year >< price > 30.00 </ price ></ book ></ bookstore > ");
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Now, in **xmlstr** variable, I got the XML like this:
[image: I have minimised maximum nodes because of data privacy, but this is what I get in variable.]

Now, when finally the response is written is displays like a plain HTLM without any formatting.

See here:
[image: Am I missing something? I tried to paste the same XML I get in xmlstr valiable to notepad and loaded it browser. It appears properly. To my best guess, I'm not able to get the proper data to stream.]

Please let me know if anyone can help here with the same.

Comment: First: please do not post code as images.If I want to test your code I have to type it over (which i'm not gonna do ;). But Your code looks like it is outputting a correct xml file and thus the browser is displaying it's content.

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD, I have added the snippet as well. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by filling my `DataTable` to `DataSet` and the used the inbuilt function `GetXML()` from `DataSet`

See the snippet below:

```
private void BuildAYSONationalFeed(HttpContext context, DataTable feedDataTable)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Portals");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(feedDataTable);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        context.Response.Write(dataSet.GetXml());
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

This did the job.

So, `GetXML()` method basically loads the data stored as tabular format in `DataSet` to XML.
I simply displayed the XML response to browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    dataTable.WriteXml(ms, true);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        string xmlstr = sr.ReadToEnd();

        //display unaltered xml in multiline textbox (= textarea in html)
        TextBox1.Text = xmlstr;

        //or htmlencode the xml for displaying it in html
        Label1.Text = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlstr);

        //or if you want to display the xml somewhat nicely you have to do some replacing
        Label2.Text = formatXML(xmlstr);
    }
}
```

The helper method for formatting the xml for displaying it in html

```
string formatXML(string xmlstr)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlstr))
    {
        return xmlstr;
    }

    //html encode the xml
    string formattedXml = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xmlstr);

    //replace the line breaks with html <br>
    formattedXml = formattedXml.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");

    //indend the xml bij replacing spaces with no break space
    formattedXml = formattedXml.Replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;");

    return formattedXml;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a ashx handler. I don't think we are allowed to create any asp control in that as it's not a page but handler.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand the problem. If the asmx sends out a correct xml you can just read it with jquery and place it somewhere ion the page.